# TeXWorks is not finding my texlive installation

Tags: texworks

I had been using the TeXWorks distro that comes with ElementaryOS 5.1 (essentially Ubuntu 18.04), but it started to crash frequently, and it was also 0.6.2 not the latest 0.6.6, so I decided to install the flatpak version. That seemed to go fine, but when I run it, it doesn't find my texlive installation (every version of TeX in the dropdown is greyed-out).

In edit/preferences/typesetting it shows the correct /usr/bin path, and under help/settings and resources, the Settings file ~/.var/app/org.tug.texworks/config/TUG/TeXworks.conf opens fine, but nothing happens when I click on the Resources ~/.var/app/org.tug.texworks/data/TUG/TeXworks, even though the directory is there. No error message either.

There are also texworks files in ~/.local/share/flatpak, and there's a ~/.TeXworks directory as well; I have no idea where these came from now, or if the new installation is trying to or should be using them. I can't find any way to change the Settings or Resources locations either.

TeXworks support won't help with the flatpak version, and flatpak doesn't help with anything except flatpak itself, so hopefully somebody here will!